# Grunt Browserify - require.resolve is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify

I am using [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) in the following way:

```
   browserify:
      build:
        files:
          '<%= paths.staticJS %>/Login.js'                : '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/login/Login.js'
          '<%= paths.staticJS %>/Password.js'             : '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/password/Password.js'
          '<%= paths.staticJS %>/RequestPasswordReset.js' : '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/password/RequestPasswordReset.js'
          '<%= paths.staticJS %>/ResetPassword.js'        : '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/password/ResetPassword.js'
          '<%= paths.staticJS %>/ClientRouter.js'         : '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/shared/ClientRouter.js'
```

Generally it's working fine, but i still have an issue,
in some part of my code i am using the node `require` module like this:

```
  chartViewPath = "../../charts/view/#{chartViewName}"
  resolvedPath = require.resolve(chartViewPath)
  chartViewModule = require.modules[resolvedPath]
```

And i'm getting the following error: `require.resolve is not a function`

I tried to expose the global require with alias in the grunt task:

```
  options:
    alias: [
      '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/login/Login.js:Login'
      '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/password/Password.js:Password'
      '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/password/RequestPasswordReset.js:RequestPasswordReset'
      '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/modules/password/ResetPassword.js:ResetPassword'
      '<%= paths.buildSrcJS %>/shared/ClientRouter.js:ClientRouter'
    ]
```

it does expose the `require` variable as a function but i still can't use the `require.resolve` or `modules` methods.

i should also mention that before moving to grunt i was using `Cakefile` to `Browserify` my files

```
task 'build','build for development environment', (options)->

  fs = require 'fs'
  path = require 'path'
  browserify = require 'browserify'
  routers = [ "modules/login/Login","shared/ClientRouter","modules/password/Password","modules/password/RequestPasswordReset", "modules/password/ResetPassword" ]
  routers.forEach((r)->
    jsSource = path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/main/#{r}.coffee")
    jsDestination = path.resolve( "#{__dirname}/../static/js/#{r.split('/').slice(-1)}.js" )
    browserified = browserify(jsSource, { entry : [] }).bundle()
    fs.writeFile(jsDestination, browserified, (err)-> if err then console.log "error writing file:#{err}")
  )
```

and in this way it's working fine and i can use `require.resolve` and `require.modules`
because for some reason in this way browserify is adding to the beginning of each entry
file these methods like in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/viatropos/1329534).

Answer (score 1):

`grunt-browserify` might depend on a different version of `browserify` than the one you were using before.  Use `npm ls` to examine the version you had before and see if it differs from the one `grunt-browerify` wants.

Other than that, I didn't see significant differences between your original script and what the Grunt plugin attempts to do.